# How to repeat a string with spaces in python 3.9

Tags: python

How to repeat a string with spaces?
This is my code:

```
a=input("enter a word:")
b=int(input("start position:"))
c=int(input("end position:"))
d=int(input("number of repetitions:"))
x=a[b:c]
print(x*d)
```

If I enter : a= Door, b=1, c=3, d=2 =>

The output is:

```
oooo
```

But I would like the output to have space between repetitions:

```
oo oo
```

What is missing?

Comment: `" ".join([x]*d)`?

Comment: @Ch3steR gotcha, I see. I'm not really sure what OP is asking then. Better variables names than `a` `b` `c` `d` might help clarify the intent.

Comment: So add a space. You won't get space characters if you don't use/add some.

Comment: @ggorlen Yeah. I commented on what I understood from the question(maybe I read too much into it).

Answer (score 2):

Here the item x is repeated d times in a list which is then printed with a space as the separator:

```
a=input("enter a word:")
b=int(input("start position:"))
c=int(input("end position:"))
d=int(input("number of repetitions:"))
x=a[b:c]
print(*[x]*d, sep=" ")
```